# Complex addition in clause where SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Complex addition in where clause :

```
select * 
from #table 
where 
    ((IsNullChamps1, 0) AND Date < 2009) + ((IsNull(#champs2, 0)) AND Date < 2008) < 90
```

This my query; I want to add the value of `(IsNullChamps1, 0)` only with `Date < 2009` and `(IsNullChamps1, 0)` with date only < 30

I will try to make it clearer. I have a table which contains 4 columns:

```
Id_table 
Champs1
Champs2
Date
```

For example :

```
            Date  2013  2011  2009  2008  2007  2006
champs            90    20    50    60    10     30
champs2           70    30    0.0   16    36     25
```

For example I want to add the value of the champs1 with date < 2008 to the value of champs 2 with date < 2013.

Comment: Please make you question more clear

Comment: Your query has lots of syntax errors in it. The real issue though is that is just doesn't make any sense what you are trying to do. Here is a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: what makes any sense in my query please. i want just to add two columns in the clause where and specifing a date for every column , Because i do not want to addition the two columns with all date in table . i know there is some erros in my query , that is why i am looking a help

Comment: Start with fixing your typo.    (IsNullChamps1, 0)   needs to be IsNull(Champs1, 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL Server 2008+, a CASE statement may be what you are looking for. It lets you do your boolean condition within a block.  Select the Champs1 when you want it or make it 0, Select the Champs2 when you want it or make it 0, then sum them and compare.

```
--Sample Data
DECLARE @mytable TABLE(
  [Date] INT NOT NULL,
  [Champs1] INT NULL,
  [Champs2] INT NULL
  )

INSERT INTO @mytable (Date, Champs1, Champs2)
VALUES (2013, 90, 70), (2011, 20, 30), (2009, 50, 0), (2008, 60, 16), (2007, 0, 36), (2006, 30, 25)

--Select statement
SELECT *
FROM @mytable
WHERE 
    (CASE WHEN Date < 2009 THEN ISNULL(Champs1, 0) ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN Date < 2013 THEN ISNULL(Champs2, 0) ELSE 0 END)
    < 90
```

Comment: yes this is query that what i was looking for , thanks a lot grayimp . this query really helped me .

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. If you feel this answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. Thanks!

Comment: hi grayimp , if i want to ignore the value 0.000 .

Comment: I'm not sure which field you mean. Which of the following are you trying to get: 1) Exclude rows where Date is 0.0, 2) Exclude rows where Champs1 is 0.0, even if Date < 2013 and Champs2 < 90, 3) Exclude rows where Champs2 is 0.0, even if Date < 2009 and Champs1 < 90, or 5) Exclude rows where Champs1 and Champs2 are both 0.0?

Comment: Hi i want to excude rows where champs 1 and champs2 are both 0.00 so i will only keep the date needed.  thanks et sorry for the late to reply

Comment: I would just add that check to your WHERE clause so you have:
    (CASE WHEN Date < 2009 THEN ISNULL(Champs1, 0) ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN Date < 2013 THEN ISNULL(Champs2, 0) ELSE 0 END)
    < 90 AND NOT (ISNULL(Champs1, 0) = 0 AND ISNULL(Champs2, 0)

Comment: Thanks so much grayimp, i will try this and be back with the resultat . with this condition i want to exclude champs 0.00 where the date is not respected  for ex : NOT (ISNULL(Champs1, 0) = 0 and Date superieur 2009 .

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to do something like this?

```
select * from #table 
where Champs1 < 2009
  AND Champs2 < 2008
  AND IsNull(Champs1,0) + IsNull(Champs2,0) < 90
```